# HTML - Writing Mode Not changing anything

Tags: html, css

Hi guys i am trying to get a header in my table to show vertically however the writing-mode is not changing anything.

CSS

```
.VerticalText
{
  writing-mode: tb-rl;
}
```

HTML

```
<td rowspan="6" id="tableHeader" class="Border">
   <h1 class="Font12 VerticalText Centre">Project Details</h1>
</td>
```

[image]

in this image the text in the blue should be vertical

Comment: Try `writing-mode: vertical-rl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`writing-mode: tb-rl;` is now Deprecated. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode

Try `writing-mode: vertical-rl`

```css
.VerticalText
{
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}
```

```html
<td rowspan="6" id="tableHeader" class="Border">
   <h1 class="Font12 VerticalText Centre">Project Details</h1>
</td>
```

Comment: Hmm, this still hasn't changed anything.

Comment: @MagicRecon so why did you mark the answer as correct?

Answer (score 0):

Changing to

```
vertical-rl;
```

fixes the issue.  I was using Atom editor with the live preview plugin which doesn't recognize the newer CSS.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful.  - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12899328)

Comment: It was also a solution to an extent that is why i posted it.